# How to create a graph using NetworkX in Python out of a point-cloud for pathfinding?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, path-finding, point-clouds

I want to create a graph using NetworkX in Python out of a point cloud for pathfinding. The point cloud is in a .las file and classified with walkable points (Ground, Stairs etc.) and not walkable points (walls, buildings etc.). Now the thing is the point cloud is decimated to an average distance of 0.5 meters from point to point. That means when I create edges in the graph that connects all walkable points it could be possible that there is a connection created that goes right through a small wall. Now my question is, how can I create a graph only with edges that don’t intersect with a wall? I thought of creating a Graph from all walkable points (average distance 0.5 m) and one with all non-walkable points and then deleting all intersecting edges. I simulated this in QGIS and made a screenshot to add to the question. The walkable Network is blue, the not Walkable Network is red. The output should be something like the green Network.

[problem: edges of the network span over walls (red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwXsf.jpg)

[result: Network whitout intersections with not walkable network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG2qd.jpg)

I tried to delete all edges that intersect :

```py
def remove_intersecting_edges(G1, G2):
    # Loop over edges in G1
    for u1, v1 in G1.edges():
        # Create LineString object for edge
        edge1 = LineString([G1.nodes[u1]['pos'], G1.nodes[v1]['pos']])
        
        # Loop over edges in G2
        for u2, v2 in G2.edges():
            # Create LineString object for edge
            edge2 = LineString([G2.nodes[u2]['pos'], G2.nodes[v2]['pos']])
            
            # Check if edges intersect
            if edge1.intersects(edge2):
              #check if edges exists and thn remove (to avoid NetworkXError: The edge 0-1983 is not in the graph):
              if G1.has_edge(u1, v1):
                G1.remove_edge(u1, v1)
              if G2.has_edge(u2, v2):
                G2.remove_edge(u2, v2)
```

Comment: Connect only walkable points that are adjacent.